# what is normalize()

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS fans..

I am new in ROS.. I want to ask you a simple question
What is function of Normalize() in  angle..

I hope someone can help me :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61553/what-is-normalize()/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a couple of variants, are you referring to a specific one, e.g. from the angles package?

Usually the functionality is to bring an angle into a unique range as all angles are the same module 2 pi. Most implementations will choose [-pi, pi], but I've also seen [0, 2 pi].

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2